# Is the complex projective plane a compact manifold with or without boundary (closed manifold)?

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space, manifolds-with-boundary

my question is the one in the title. (My motivation is to understand in which way Freedman's classification of compact simply-connected 4-manifolds implies the Poincare conjecture for 4-manifolds, as the complex projective plane should be a counter example, i.e. compact, simply-connected ,(closed or not? that is the question), non-homeomorphic to the 4-sphere.)

Thank you for help

I wish a nice day

Comment: Yes it's a closed manifold.  Check the definition of the Poincaré conjecture in dimensions $>3$. In particular, check the hypotheses, which concern more than just the fundamental group.

Comment: It's easy to see that it's boundaryless by looking at the charts: Every chart domain of the standard atlas is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$. If there were a boundary, some of these charts would have to be homeomorphic to a half-space instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathbb{CP}^2$ is a compact manifold without boundary (equivalently, a closed manifold). But the (topological) [$4$-dimensional Poincare conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture) does not state that every closed simply connected $4$-manifold without boundary is homeomorphic to the $4$-sphere (because, as you observe, this statement is clearly false). It states that every closed $4$-manifold which is homotopy equivalent to the $4$-sphere is homeomorphic to the $4$-sphere.

Freedman's classification proves this because a closed $4$-manifold which is homotopy equivalent to the $4$-sphere must both be simply connected and have trivial intersection form (this is necessary and sufficient), and as the trivial intersection form is even there is a unique corresponding homeomorphism class of $4$-manifolds which must be the $4$-sphere. (Freedman's classification also implies that the $4$-sphere has vanishing Kirby-Siebenmann invariant, but of course we already knew that because we already knew that the $4$-sphere admits a smooth structure.)

It's a nice exercise to show that a closed $n$-manifold, $n \ge 2$, is homotopy equivalent to the $n$-sphere iff it is simply connected and has the same integral homology as the $n$-sphere. When $n = 3$ the second condition is redundant, but in general it's not.